# Access resources (CSS, HTML, images, JS) through servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'd like to know if anyone has a solution to access resources of a website through a servlet only. 
I have all my resources under WEB-INF. In other words, I don't want users to have direct access to any of my resources.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) for that.

```
URL resource = getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/file.ext");
File file = new File(resource.getPath());
// ...
```

You can even use [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get an [`InputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) directly:

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/file.ext");
// ...
```

As you can see in the examples, the [`ServletContext`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) is available in servlets by the inherited [`GenericServlet#getServletContext()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getServletContext%28%29) method.

---

That said, the phrase *I don't want users to have direct access to any of my resources.* is a bit contradicting. You're serving those resources by a servlet anyway? A servlet is directly accessible by URL. How is that different from "direct access"? Or do you just want to control the access based on some conditions? I'd say, a [`Filter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is more suitable for this task.

Usually one would only fully hide the JSP files from direct access. In a Servlet which acts as front controller (according the MVC pattern) you could then forward requests to JSP files using [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) which you in turn can obtain by [`ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29).

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I thought the original question was saying, "I don't want users to be able to view resources in their browser by typing in a direct URL". Putting your files you want to prevent "direct access" into WEB-INF and having the servlet get access to the resource sounds like "best practice" to me.

Comment: @WineSoaked: usually the concern is JSP files only, because you would like to hide the views in a fully MVC-controlled application. But for static resources like CSS/HTML/Images/JS? No. The problem is to be solved differently. It's only unclear *how* since the actual functional requirement is unclear as well.

Comment: You make a good point. But what if the servlet is generating the resources at runtime (not unheard of in my experience, even though I disagree with the practice)? If there are fragments of these CSS/HTML/JS/etc. that are processed through a servlet, that's a plausible use. If, however, you're just funneling the bytes from WEB-INF to the browser without doing anything, then the servlet is playing a proxy role, for which it is ill-suited.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide jsp from the end user. In fact, you don't even have to deploy original jsp files with your web application, you can precompile them:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web%20Application%20Compilation

And the only way to hide html/js/css files is not to use them. Anything that's sent to the browser can be viewed there.